# Retrieve columns based on the case size defined

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table with few columns. In one column I have string like

```
abc,efg,gst,jh,jhyg
```

Now I want to retrieve the string based on the case size the user defines. For example the case size is 2 then my retrieved string should be "abc,efg".

Please help me how to achieve it.

Comment: Question should be more clear.

Comment: I have a column as serial number and it has multiple values like "abc,efg,gst,jh,jhyg" in one row, now i have a variable 'CaseSize' which can be any integer value For example if the case size is 2 then my output should be "abc,efg" and if casesize 3 then "abc,efg,gst". Please help me how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a row_number function like shown below

```
DECLARE @CaseSize int = 2

;WITH OrderedOrders AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) as row, data FROM test
  )
SELECT data
from OrderedOrders
where row <= @CaseSize
```

I have created [a sample on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11bd91/21); I hope it helps!